# Пример "Bird's eye view"

Tags: c++, graphics

Здравствуйте. Разбираюсь с opencv по книге Брадски "Learning OpenCV". Запустил пример 12-1 "Bird's eye view", всё нормально - работает, даже что-то показывает. Т.к. я не очень понимаю суть "Bird's eye view" (да и материала по нему практически нет), объясните пожалуйста, для чего оно нужно, какие должны быть входные параметры и что мы должны получить на выходе. Или укажите, где можно про это прочитать. Заранее благодарен.

Comment: Теперь я понял, что "Bird's eye view" предназначен для преобразования изображения снятого под углом, в такое изображение которое выглядит как, если бы мы смотрели на него перпендикулярно. Может кто-нибудь мне подскажет где можно прочитать, про "Bird's eye view" и его реализацию на OpenCV(кроме этой книги).

Comment: Вопрос остаётся в силе.